# Prove that$ f\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i\Bigg) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f(x_i) $ for a convex function "f"

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

*Let f be a convex function defined on a set I.* *If* $x_1, x_2, ...,x_n \in I$, *and* $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 ,...,\lambda_n \in [0,1]$ *with* $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1$ *then prove that* 
$$
f\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i\Bigg) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f(x_i)
$$

I have no idea where to start, except to use the definition of a convex function:
$$
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)
$$

Anyone any ideas of how to approach this problem?

Comment: this question is a clear duplicate,,,therefor i vote to close and delete my answer

Answer (score 1):

For $n = 2$ you know it's true.
Let's proceed by induction on $n$: let
$$\tau_i = \frac{\lambda_i}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} \lambda_j}$$

Then:

\begin{align*}
f\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j x_j\right) &= f\left(\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\lambda_j\right)\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\tau_jx_j + \lambda_nx_n\right) \\
&\leq\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\lambda_j\right)\cdot f\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \tau_jx_j\right) + \lambda_nf(x_n) \\
&\leq\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\lambda_j\right)\cdot \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \tau_jf(x_j) + \lambda_n f(x_n) = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j f(x_j)
\end{align*}

Where the second inequality comes from the induction hypothesis and the first from the property for $n=2$.